# DataFrame need help to organise columns and rows of a DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather simple DataFrame but problems appear when I try to reorganize it to provide a specific rows and columns order for another application.

I tried using MultiIndexing but I failed to solve the complexity

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([('adc','20030103','USD','KLP','0.41'),
              ('adc','20030103','USD','TRF','0.59'),
              ('adc','20030104','USD','UTC','0.35'),
              ('adc','20030104','USD','ZSE','0.65')],
             columns=('pfl','date','cur','ID','W'))
```

I expect an ouptut like this :

```
pfl  adc
date 20030103
cur  USD
ID   W
KLP  0.41
TRF  0.59
pfl adc
date 20030104
cur  USD
ID   W
UTC  0.35
ZSE  0.65
```

Comment: That loojs like the definiton of `stack()`. Just do `df.stack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Recommended

```
df.set_index(['pfl', 'date', 'cur'])

                   ID     W
pfl date     cur           
adc 20030103 USD  KLP  0.41
             USD  TRF  0.59
    20030104 USD  UTC  0.35
             USD  ZSE  0.65
```

---

#### What you asked for

```
a = ['pfl', 'date', 'cur']
b = ['ID', 'W']

pd.DataFrame(sum(
    [[*zip(a, k)] + [b] + [*zip(*map(d.get, b))]
     for k, d in df.groupby(a)], []
))

       0         1
0    pfl       adc
1   date  20030103
2    cur       USD
3     ID         W
4    KLP      0.41
5    TRF      0.59
6    pfl       adc
7   date  20030104
8    cur       USD
9     ID         W
10   UTC      0.35
11   ZSE      0.65
```

Comment: Thank you. it looks great. How you define 'cols' ?

Comment: Whoops, `cols` was changed to `a` (-:

Answer (score 1):

`stack` is what you are looking for:

```
df.stack().droplevel(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but i have 2 'ID' and 'W' per 'date', and the stack() provide only 1